# How to make Page Tab app visible

Tags: tabs, facebook-page

I created a page tab app for my fan page.  It's a simple html page that displays a photo. It appears to have been successfully created and I can add it to the page.  The icon appears blow "friend activity" on the left.  I've edited the page permission so the page tab is the default landing tab.  However, when I visit the page, the new tab page is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Default landing tab is intended to be default only to users visiting a page who is not yet fan of that page.

> default landing tab for users who have not liked and are not admins of this Page